# Extract and format timestamp in bash

Tags: bash, shell, xargs

I have script that returns a list of files with the full path to each file. For e.g. - `root/folder/file@1610565763436`. Hence, the output looks like

```
/root/folder/file@1610565763436
/root/folder/file@1610568241000
/root/folder/file@1610597041000
/root/folder/file@1610625841000
/root/folder/file@1610654641000
/root/folder/file@1610683441000
/root/folder/file@1610712242000
/root/folder/file@1610741041000
/root/folder/file@1610769841000
/root/folder/file@1610798641000
/root/folder/file@1610827441000
/root/folder/file@1610856241000
/root/folder/file@1610885041000
/root/folder/file@1610913841000
```

I want to format the output such that I get the human readable timestamp as the output only. I tried doing a `cut -d "@" -f 2` to get the timestamp but piping that to a xargs and running a date command does not work, for me.
i.e. `/bin/bash scriptToGetFiles | cut -d "@" -f 2 | xargs date -d {}`.

FWIW, running the above with `xargs -t` returns an error

```
date -d @ 1610565763436 1610568241000 1610597041000 1610625841000 1610654641000 1610683441000 1610712242000 1610741041000 1610769841000 1610798641000  
date: extra operand ‘1610568241000’
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions or pointers.

Comment: pipe it to `cut -f2 -d@ | cut -c1-10 | perl -lape '$_=localtime($_)'` to do it without forking date.  Useful if you have, say, hundreds of such lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU date:

```
$ echo /root/folder/file@1610565763436 | cut -d@ -f2 | xargs -I '{}' echo {} / 1000  | bc  | xargs -I '{}' date --date=@{}
Wed Jan 13 20:22:43 CET 2021
```

On FreeBSD:

```
$ echo /root/folder/file@1610565763436 | cut -d@ -f2 | xargs -I '{}' echo {} / 1000  | bc  | xargs  date -r
Wed Jan 13 20:22:43 CET 2021
```

Answer (score 0):

With plain bash, `printf` can format Epoch times:

```bsh
processThatOutputsStuff | while IFS=@ read -r path date; do
    printf '%(%c)T\n' "${date%???}"
done
```

`${date%???}` is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) that removes the last 3 characters from the variable's value.

If you want a different datetime format, replace `%c`.